# Negative margin causes content to move during zoom

Tags: html, css, margin

I can not for the life of me find why the information in my `content2` `div` keeps moving on zoom in, I imagine it is due to using negative margin. Is there any way around this? Any ideas or fixes?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Programs R Us</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<div id="wrap">

<!--header starts-->
<div id="header">
<div id="name">
<h1>Programs <span>R</span> Us</h1>
</div><!--end name-->   
<div id="nav"><br>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="programs.html">Our Programs</a></li>
    </ol>
</div><!--end nav-->
</div><!--end header-->
<!--header ends-->

<!--content1 starts-->
<div id="content1">
<img src="images/placeholder.png" width="400" height="323" alt="logo"> 
<div id="imgright">
<h2>What We Do</h2>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div id="button"><a href=#>
<h4>Request A Program</h4></a>
</div><!--end button-->
</div><!--end imgright-->
</div><!--end content1-->
<!--content1 ends-->

<!--content2 starts-->
<div id="content2">
<div id="one">
<img src="images/arrow.png" width="70px" height="50px;" alt="arrow1">
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p> 
</div><!--end one-->

<div id="two"> 
<img src="images/arrow.png" width="70px" height="50px;" alt="arrow1">
  <h3>About Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end two-->

<div id="three">
<img src="images/arrow.png" width="70px" height="50px;" alt="arrow1">
  <h3>View Our Programs</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end three-->  
</div><!--end content2-->
<!--content2 ends-->

<!--footer starts-->
<div id="footer">
<h5>Insert some footer information, copyright information also</h5>
</div><!--end footer-->
<!--footer ends-->

</div><!--end wrap-->
</div><!--end body-->
<div id="blue">
</div><!--end blue-->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
    overflow: auto;
}

#body{
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:0;
}

#wrap{
    width:1124px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:5px;
}

#header h1{
    font-size:36px;
    font-family: Terminal, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

#header span{
    font-size:100px;
    color:black;
    font-family:"brush script std", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#nav{
    margin-top:-90px;
    margin-bottom:75px;
    margin-right:40px;
    background-color:#2e3192;
    float:right;
    margin-left:-300px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
}

#nav ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    background-color:#2e3192;
    margin-top:-10px;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#nav a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: black;
}

#content1 img{
    margin-left:25px;
}

#imgright{
    margin-left:445px;
    margin-top:-389px;
}

#button h4{
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:24px;
    color:white;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#button{
    margin-left:-400px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-bottom:110px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    width:220px;
}

#button a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#button a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:white;
}

h2{
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:48px;
}

#imgright p{
    color: white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#content2{
    background-color:#2e3192;
    overflow-x:visible;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#one, #two, #three{width:341.3px;}

#one img, #two img, #three img{padding-right:10px;}

#one h3, #two h3, #three h3{
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:white;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    border-left-width:3px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:white;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-top:4px;
}

#one h3{
    font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
#one p{
    font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
}

#two h3{
    font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:-46px;
}
#two p{
    font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
}

#three h3{
    font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:-46px;
}

#three p{
    font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
}

#one{
    margin-top:50px;
}

#two{
    margin-top:-270px;
    margin-left:360px;
}

#three{
    margin-top:-140px;
    margin-left:720px;
    margin-bottom:0px;        
}

#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer h5{
    margin-left:300px;
}

#blue{
    position:absolute;
    top:619px;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:#2e3192;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Image of the problem**
[image: margins moving]

**Image of the problem**
[image: jsfiddle, i think]

Comment: Where's your `<html>` tag? That can cause problems like that.

Comment: Wow i cant believe i missed that, however that wasnt the problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing a http://jsfiddle.net or link to the page that's showing the problem. You're right, it is often margins or padding, but staring at the markup is sorta pointless.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i did provide a picture of what is hapening, but ill try to provide a fiddle, never used it before and i find them kind of useless if i provide code and a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to clean up your CSS. It's a mess, difficult to navigate, and contains redundant definitions.
2. Most of your CSS uses explicit values for width, position, margins, etc. Try to make your styling work without having absolute values for *everything*. Try using relative values; this makes the design easier to manage and less prone to weird rendering glitches.
3. Lastly, your question is somewhat difficult to understand. Yes, the code and picture are helpful but **providing a working example would be much better**. It makes troubleshooting much easier for the SO community.

---

Anyway, see if this helps. Be sure to clear out the current CSS definitions for `#one, #two, #three`. I made minor changes in the working example mainly so I could get the page to render correctly.

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/olaxaj/1/

**Relevant CSS**

```
#one, #two, #three {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:.5em;
}
```

Comment: This is very much a neat website that i will for sure use in the future. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry for the harsh criticism. I just wanted you to be aware so you can improve your work and provide more succinct questions in the future.

Comment: I opened myself to the criticism, it's much appreciated.